# UIAccessibility issue - becomesFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

I have a `UIViewController` whose `viewDidAppear` triggers a `textField` keyboard on landing.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [self.valueTextField becomesFirstResponder];
 }
```

When the voice over is enabled, the default behavior is to start from the `navigationbar` item's title label. Since the view launches the keyboard on start, the voice over focus is on the `textfield` for a split second before it starts with the `navigationbaritem's` title label. Is there a way to avoid the voice over to focus on the `textfield` and start with the title label on the navigation item?